# MS Access. Updating a query with a form command button

Tags: forms, ms-access

very new to Access and I have what is probably a simple question that I've spent the last 2 hours researching and can not find an answer for.

I have a simple form, frmCheckOut, with two text boxes, DateCheckedOut and DueDate, and a command button, updateButton. The DateCheckedOut can be any date while DueDate is a calculated field (=[CheckOutDate]+14). The command button merely opens the forms record source query (qryOverdue).

Entering data into the forms DateCheckedOut correctly calculates the DueDate in the form,  and clicking the button opens the associated query with the DateCheckedOut accurately reflecting the forms current information, but the DueDate with the calculated field is not updating correctly in the query.

Why is DateCheckedOut correctly updating in the query while the calculated field of DueDate is not?

(the button was built using the event builder, simple code but here it is

```
Private Sub updateButton_Click()
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryOverdue"
End Sub
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Opening a SELECT query does not update fields.

Saving calculated data is usually not advised. The DueDate value can be calculated in query or textbox whenever needed. Or even use table Calculated field.

Suggest you give controls a name different from the fields they are bound to, such as tbxOut and tbxDue.

However, if you must save, then use the AfterUpdate event of tbxOut with expression to populate the DueDate field:

`Me!DueDate = Me.tbxDue`

or

`Me!DueDate = Me.tbxOut + 14`